How do I edit 'authDomain' in project config?
I'm new to Firebase and I have a simple web project (plain js) that uses the following structure when booting up:
HTML Scripts:
  <!-- Firebase -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/10.12.2/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

Function on page load:
function _startFirebase() {
  let app = firebase.app();
  let features = [
    'auth',
    'database',
    'firestore',
    'functions',
    'messaging',
    'storage',
    'analytics',
    'remoteConfig',
    'performance',
  ].filter(feature => typeof app[feature] === 'function');
  console.log(`Firebase SDK loaded with ${features.join(', ')}`);
  firebase.auth().currentUser;
}

For the authentication, I have use Google with the signInWithRedirect option.
async function _signInGoogle() {
    try {
        await firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        await firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        _displayErrorMessage(error)
    }
}

When using a different domain other than 'firebaseapp.com', I noticed that I'm unable do sign in. I've already added the custom domain into console.cloud.google.com Web Client Credentials, so now the only thing left if I'm not wrong is to edit 'authDomain' in my config file with the custom domain.
How can I do that with my current approach? I saw from some Firebase official videos that the commom approach is to have an index file with initializeApp(firebaseConfig), but since I'm not handling my app this way I was wondering if there is a different way.
I've tried using initializeApp in the beggining of my _startFirebase function, but it doesn't work since it was already booted (app/duplicate-app error).
